# Dependency injection not working on one the the tax collector class

Tags: magento2, tax, dependency-injection, preference, override-model

I am trying to override mapItem method from "Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector" using below code. However code written in my local module's class is not invoked.

**VendorName\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector" type="VendorName\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector" />
</config>
```

**VendorName\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector.php**

```
<?php


namespace VendorName\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem;

Class CommonTaxCollector extends \Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector {

/**
 * Map an item to item data object
 *
 * @param \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterfaceFactory $itemDataObjectFactory
 * @param AbstractItem $item
 * @param bool $priceIncludesTax
 * @param bool $useBaseCurrency
 * @param string $parentCode
 * @return \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterface
 */
public function mapItem(
    \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterfaceFactory $itemDataObjectFactory,
    AbstractItem $item,
    $priceIncludesTax,
    $useBaseCurrency,
    $parentCode = null
) {
    $objmanager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $logger = $objmanager->get("Psr\Log\LoggerInterface");
    $logger->debug("Testing if local method is called");

    if (!$item->getTaxCalculationItemId()) {
        $sequence = 'sequence-' . $this->getNextIncrement();
        $item->setTaxCalculationItemId($sequence);
    }
    /** @var \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterface $itemDataObject */
    $itemDataObject = $itemDataObjectFactory->create();
    $itemDataObject->setCode($item->getTaxCalculationItemId())
        ->setQuantity($item->getQty())
        ->setTaxClassKey(
            $this->taxClassKeyDataObjectFactory->create()
                ->setType(TaxClassKeyInterface::TYPE_ID)
                ->setValue($item->getProduct()->getTaxClassId())
        )
        ->setIsTaxIncluded($priceIncludesTax)
        ->setType(self::ITEM_TYPE_PRODUCT);

    if ($useBaseCurrency) {
        if (!$item->getBaseTaxCalculationPrice()) {
            $item->setBaseTaxCalculationPrice($item->getBaseCalculationPriceOriginal());
        }
        $itemDataObject->setUnitPrice($item->getBaseTaxCalculationPrice())
            ->setDiscountAmount($item->getBaseDiscountAmount());
    } else {
        if (!$item->getTaxCalculationPrice()) {
            $item->setTaxCalculationPrice($item->getCalculationPriceOriginal());
        }
        $itemDataObject->setUnitPrice($item->getTaxCalculationPrice())
            ->setDiscountAmount($item->getDiscountAmount());
    }

    $itemDataObject->setParentCode($parentCode);

    return $itemDataObject;
}

}
```

Comment: I also tried clearing generation folder along with cache but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since dependency injection did not work on **CommonTaxCollector** class, alternatively I had to override mapItem method using dependency injection on other files (mentioned below in di.xml) which are extending the **class : Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax" type="VendorName\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax" />
    <preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Subtotal" type="VendorName\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Subtotal" />
</config>
```

However it would be great if someone can suggest a way to override **Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector** directly.

Comment: Can you explain the full process ? It's not working for me.